# Apex callout with a client certificate

Tags: integration, rest, post

I have written one Rest service which is returning a access token to resend it to endsystem to get the final response but we are getting **"Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException"** error.
Please help me to get the cause of this.
Please find below code snippet:

```
 HttpRequest req3 = new HttpRequest();
req3.setClientCertificateName('Certificate name');
 req3.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req3.setBody('xml_in ='+accesstoken); // 
req3.setMethod('POST');
req3.setEndpoint(endPoint);
HttpResponse res3 = h3.send(req3);
```

Comment: Please share code to check issue.

Comment: Please use an [edit] to include the relevant code and verbatim error message. Please *do not* include your access tokens or other secret values.

Comment: Thanks David Reed for the updation.
I added it by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with locating a certificate based on its name. Supply a correct name and your code will work. SF behavior is a bit bizarre in this case, you might have found a bug.

When executing this Apex in our Dev Ed org and supplying a valid name of a non-expired certificate, everything works:

```
String endpoint = 'https://www.google.com';
String accesstoken = 'foo';
Http h3 = new Http();
HttpRequest req3 = new HttpRequest();
req3.setClientCertificateName('SomeCorrectCertificateName');
req3.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req3.setBody('xml_in ='+accesstoken); // 
req3.setMethod('POST');
req3.setEndpoint(endpoint);
HttpResponse res3 = h3.send(req3);
```

The name of the certificate can be found by looking at one of the certs in Certificates section under Setup > Certificate and Key Management. The "name" of a cert you want to use in `setClientCertificateName(...)` method is the value of `Unique Name` field on the certificate detail screen.

Executing the same Apex code but with a completely random name of the cert yields a legible error. Moreover, when executing it as anon Apex from developer console, SF detects the invalid cert based on a bogus name and doesn't let the execution to go through!

Where it gets interesting is if the same Apex code is run with the name of the cert set to `Certificate name`. Even though there's no cert with that name in our org, the execution...proceeds and then sort of hangs. Yikes! It sounds like a bug where this default-looking name is somehow being referenced in SF backend. We recommend you open a case with SF support and let them know about this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help I found the solution Actually the problem was with out request XML only and we already have correct signed certificate.
Our code is working properly fine now.