# Is it possible to upload a self-signed certificate into Salesforce for callout purpose?

Tags: callout, security, api-client-certificate

We need to make a callout to an external system. The external system uses a self-generated certificate to verify the caller. So is it possible to upload a certificate into Salesforce for this purpose?

The only two places I can recall is connected app JWT bearer token and two-way SSL. But since this is a callout to a third party system I don't think either of this should apply. Currently we are uploading it as a document or static resource and read the file as string. But is there a better solution for this?

Comment: @identigral I am not asking for using a SF signed cert or CA signed cert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For callouts that need to implement mutual auth in SSL (aka 2-way SSL) with your own, self-signed cert:

1. Drop your cert + private key into a JKS keystore and import it via Certificate and Key Management admin UI. Even though JKS supports a cert-only entry, that won't work here. SF will only import a JKS with one or more entry of type `PrivateKeyEntry`. The `PrivateKeyEntry` is a public/private keypair item.
2. Use the cert in an Apex callout: [Apex callout with a client certificate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275514/apex-callout-with-a-client-certificate)