# Import CA-Signed Certificate from One Org into Another via MetadataAPI

Tags: metadata-api, security, certificates, sandboxpostcopy

I am trying to automate the set up of some of my lower sandboxes.

In my SandboxPostCopy class, I'm using the FinancialForce MetadataAPI wrapper MetadataService to query and upsert a certificate. (Update the prod cert to be the development cert).

In a dev sandbox where the CA-Signed certificate has already been uploaded, I have downloaded the Certificate (.CRT) and saved it as a static resource into the other lower environment.

I can query the cert via the metadata api and get the record and can update the master label and can even update the `Certificate.Content` to be the string export of the content of the existing `Certificate.Content`, but when I attempt to update the content to the exportedCRT.body resource I get a: `"Couldn't find a certificate chain within the uploaded content"` error response.

Is what I'm trying to do not possible? Any recommendations on how to automate this process?

**Code:**

```
StaticResource exportedCRT = [SELECT id, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE name = 'exportedCRT'];
system.debug(exportedCRT.body);

MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
MetadataService.Certificate myExistingProdCert = (MetadataService.Certificate)service.readMetadata('Certificate', new String[] {'myExistingProdCert'}).getRecords()[0];
system.debug(myExistingProdCert.content);

myExistingProdCert.content = String.valueOf(exportedCRT.body);

myExistingProdCert.masterLabel = 'convertedToDevCert';

List <MetadataService.UpsertResult> results = service.upsertMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] {myExistingProdCert});

system.debug(results);
```

**Salesforce Certificate Metadata API Documentation:** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_certificate.htm

Comment: Hi S.B. did you finally manage to upload the certificate ? Could the error you got be related to the requirements described in this post ? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275721/is-it-possible-to-upload-a-self-signed-certificate-into-salesforce-for-callout-p?rq=1